# Counting distinct values per polygon in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, point-in-polygon, count

In QGIS I have a list of points, each with a town it's located in and a status, either *'new'* or *'existing'*. So something like:

| ID | town | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Alicetown | new |
| 02 | Alicetown | new |
| 03 | Alicetown | existing |
| 04 | Bobsburgh | existing |
| 05 | Bobsburgh | new |

I can count how many points are in each town (Alicetown: 3, Bobsburgh: 2), but I'd like to count how many new and existing points are in each (Alicetown: New: 2, Existing: 1; Bobsburgh: New: 1, Existing: 1).

I could just make a column for existing and new but I figured there has to be an easier way.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? I've tried SQL but I don't really know enough about it to get it to do what I want.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please [Edit] the Question to show what SQL you tried, and what the result was, , so we can recommend a fix.

Comment: What are you expecting to achieve as the final output, a new column in existing layer, a new table, a new layer etc. ?

Comment: I'm probably *expecting* a table but really, I'd be okay with any kind of output. Another comment already helped me to achieve what I was trying to do but I'd gladly learn about other methods too.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps the simplest way is to use the *Statistics by category* tool. It creates a new table, summarising your input.

Select the fields by which to categorise, and leave `Field to calculate statistics on` blank to get the count only:

[image]

##### Result

[image]

Comment: Oh yea...that's what I was trying to do. I did the initially count with this tool but it never occurred to me I could just add more fields with categories :'D
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

With SQL and a Virtual Layer you can try:

```sql
select town, type, count(*) pointcount, geometry
from pointlayer
group by town, type
```

[image]